# python Multiprocessing: What are ways I can reduce sy process overhead?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing - and I may interpreting this wrong - but as I run my programs I notice the more processes I spawn the more 'sy' goes up on my linux computer.  For example:

```
Cpu(s): 14.0%us, 24.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 58.8%id,  0.0%wa,  2.2%hi,  0.0%si,  0.8%st
```

The more processes I spawn the higher the sy process goes and the actual process just gets half'ed(so it was 20%/cpu before it goes to 10%/cpu) and ideal cpu remains the same(almost 60%). I'm not sure if this is a linux question or python question but is there any thing I can do to reduce this number and allow my programs to use more available cpu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system CPU time is time used by processes inside the kernel. If you have such a big ratio of system CPU to user CPU, it probably means that your process is doing a lot of system calls.

Don't think that this is lost time: the kernel is doing something useful for your process.

You might try to e.g. lower the rate of system calls by notably increasing your buffer sizes. Or maybe your processes have too much synchronization primitives.

You might use `strace` to find out about system calls done by your processes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to read the output but I'll research it.  Its just so weird, my full output is: Cpu(s): 14.0%us, 24.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 58.8%id,  0.0%wa,  2.2%hi,  0.0%si,  0.8%st but if I spawn more proceses the sys goes higher but the ideal stays similar. But your right, i am sync'ing a shared variable between all my proceses maybe thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Its more likely a hardware question.

Some key things:

- How much RAM is free?
- Are you using Swap space?
- How many CPUs do you have?
- Is your app heavy on calculations?
- How large is the shared variable(s)?
- Does your app have any I/O?

If your app has a lot of output, you may want to look into a database option and insert the values into a table.  This will add caching and control traffic flow between processes. No need to share a variable which may eventually cause other issues when the result set increases over time.

There may be some other tweaks you can do to Linux's memory to help.
Number of open files may be one.  I can check which proc settings you can optimize if needed.  It will help a little, but I think you may be running into a hardware wall.

Another option is to setup the manager to spawn to other servers, and then run processes there.  You will need to ssh to a machine and pass an arg if the process is master or slave. It can be done by adding an **init** override in the manager to redirect the processes.

Hope this helps
Rich